# go programming POST FormValue can't be printed

Tags: go

Before I being a bit of background, I am very new to go programming language. I am running go on Win 7, latest go package installer for windows. I'm not good at coding but I do like some challenge of learning a new language. I wanted to start learn Erlang but found go very interesting based on the GO I/O videos in youtube.

I'm having problem with capturing POST form values in GO. I spend three hours yesterday to get go to print a POST form value in the browser and failed miserably. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can anyone point me to the right direction? I can easily do this in another language like C#, PHP, VB, ASP, Rails etc. I have search the entire interweb and haven't found a working sample. Below is my sample code.

**Here is Index.html page**

```
{{ define "title" }}Homepage{{ end }}

{{ define "content" }}
    <h1>My Homepage</h1>

    <p>Hello, and welcome to my homepage!</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
    <p> Enter your name : <input type="text" name="username"> </P>
    <p> <button>Go</button>
    </form>
    <br /><br />

{{ end }}
```

**Here is the base page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{ template "title" . }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="contents">
            {{ template "content" . }}
        </section>
        <footer id="footer">
            My homepage 2012 copy
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**now some go code**

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "http"
    "strings"
    "html/template"

)

var index = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
  "templates/_base.html",
  "templates/index.html",
))


func GeneralHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    index.Execute(w, nil)
     if r.Method == "POST" {
        a := r.FormValue("username")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hi %s!",a); //<-- this variable does not rendered in the browser!!!

    }
}

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    remPartOfURL := r.URL.Path[len("/hello/"):] 
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello %s!", remPartOfURL)
}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", GeneralHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/hello/", helloHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:81", nil)
}
```

Thanks!

PS: Very tedious to add four space before every line of code in stackoverflow especially when you are copy pasting. Didn't find it very user friendly or is there an easier way?

Comment: As for the "four" space .. there is a little button in the tool bar to indent the code, is not very intuitive though as you have just discovered.

Comment: Where are you expecting it to be printed out? The code you have will send it to the browser page after all the html is printed.

Comment: Yes, I want it to render in the browser which is not happening. Sorry didn't use the correct terminology. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Some points: you need to update to `"net/http"` for go1. Also, you should check if there's an error returned from `http.ListenAndServe("localhost:81", nil)`. Also, you need to remove `strings` .. it's not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to the ResponseWriter (by calling Execute) before reading the value from the request is clearing it out.

You can see this in action if you use this request handler:

```
func GeneralHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Println(r.Method)
   fmt.Println(r.URL)
   fmt.Println("before",r.FormValue("username"))
   index.Execute(w, nil)
   if r.Method == "POST" {
     fmt.Println("after",r.FormValue("username"))
   } 
 }
```

This will print out before and after. However, in this case:

```
func GeneralHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println(r.Method)
  fmt.Println(r.URL)
  index.Execute(w, nil)
  if r.Method == "POST" {
    fmt.Println("after",r.FormValue("username"))
  }
}
```

The after value will be blank.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! I got it to work the way I wanted with your help.

Comment: wow you helped me as well! But why is it writing to http.ResponseWriter affects the values in http.Request?

And why it only happen to POST data only.. (GET is ok).

by the way, I don't use the execute() function but it still happen, so it's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: @LawrenceMok Yes, writing anything will close the response body. Check this blog post for more detail: http://blog.renzuocheng.com/2012/11/go-lang-http-invalid-read-on-closed-request-body/

Comment: Thank you @minikomi , it's really tricky :)

So from now I will remember to grab and take anything I want before saying something lol, otherwise I ended up with empty hand.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for html/template the second argument to Execute should be the data you want to put in the template.

Add a {{.}} somewhere in your template and then pass the string you want printed in as the second argument. It should get rendered as part of the template.